# Tomcat 7.0.28 directory listing of a specific folder in bin path

Tags: tomcat7

I developed a project that holds all the files and folder in the tomcat bin path.
I need to access a server directory for example "home" which resides in tomcat bin folder through url. Also list all sub folders and files that resides in "home" folder and allow download option for the user. The user may download any file or folder that resides in "home" folder.